# Plot subgroup labels with bar graph using pandas & matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Good afternoon,

I am trying to plot this sample data in a way that grouping is maintained on the actual graph, but I couldn't find a way/method to get these labels added this way with `matplotlib` (*the provided example is done using Excel*). Please refer to the first graph provided below and pay attention to the nicely nested grouping "London -> Switch 1, Switch3 -> Interface"

```
>>> data = {
   'Location': ['NYC', 'NYC', 'NYC', 'NYC', 'LON', 'LON', 'LON', 'TKY', 'TKY', 'TKY'], 
   'Device': ['Device1', 'Device2', 'Device3', 'Device1', 'Switch1', 'Switch1', 'Switch3', 'Router1', 
   'Router2', 'Router2'], 
   'Interface': ['Et1', 'Et2', 'Et3', 'Et2', 'Et1', 'Et3', 'Et22', 'Gi1', 'Gi1', 'Gi2'], 
   'Errors': [69, 58, 16, 83, 58, 78, 16, 30, 33, 64]}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to keep this structure when plotting with `matplotlib` too, but all my attempts were not very successful so far ...

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

[image: Graph using Excel]

And here is what the `matplotlib` graph looks like:

[image]

### **SOLUTION**

I really wanted to post this solution so it can stay here for completeness. I had to add on to the code I found within the `duplicated thread` and here it is.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos], 
        transform=ax.transAxes, color='gray')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

def my_label(my_index, level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)

    if level == df.index.nlevels-1:
        return [(x, 1) for x in labels]
    else:
        x = Counter()

        x.update(labels)

        return x.items()
    
def label_group_bar_table(ax,df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in my_label(df.index, level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos) * scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', 
                transform=ax.transAxes, size=12, color='gray')   
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
        ypos -= .05

def autonotate(df): 
    for num, entry in enumerate(df.reset_index().iterrows()):
        num, row = entry
        location, device, interface, errors = row
        ax.text(num, errors*1.02, errors, ha='center', size=12, color='black')

>>> df = rdf.groupby(['Location','Device','Interface']).sum()
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot()
>>> df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, ax=fig.gca(), figsize=(20,7), color='orange')
>>> labels = ['' for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
>>> ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
>>> ax.set_xlabel('')
>>> label_group_bar_table(ax, df)
>>> fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=.1*df.index.nlevels)
>>> autonotate(df)
>>> plt.tight_layout()
>>> plt.show()
```

This way I was able to produce the following diagram, which is pretty close to what I needed:

[image]